# Jest - How To Test a Fetch() Call That Returns A Rejected Promise?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, ts-jest, jest-fetch-mock

I have the following function that uses `fetch()` to make an API call:

```
export async function fetchCars(dealershipId) {
  return request('path/to/endpoint/' + dealershipId)
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.ok === false) {
        return Promise.reject();
      }
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((cars) => {
      return parseMyCars(cars);
    });
}
```

I want to test when the call fails (specifically when `return Promise.reject()` is returned).  I have the following Jest test right now:

```
(fetch as jest.Mock).mockImplementation(() =>
    Promise.resolve({ ok: false })
);
const result = await fetchCars(1);
expect(request).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/path/to/endpoint/1');
expect(result).toEqual(Promise.reject());
```

but I get a `Failed: undefined` message when running the test.  I've tried using:

```
(fetch as jest.Mock).mockRejectedValue(() =>
  Promise.resolve({ ok: false })
);
```

but get a similar `Failed: [Function anonymous]` message.

What's the proper way to test for the rejected promise here?

Comment: `const result = await fetchCars(1);` throws an error, because the promise rejects, so the test fails, the function call ends and the assertions aren't reached. `expect(result).toEqual(Promise.reject());` doesn't make sense anyway - the result of awaiting a rejected promise isn't a rejected promise, an error gets thrown. Also note testing errors is always tricky because you can accidently write code where the non-error path is a false positive. Per https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous you probably want to use `.rejects`.

Answer (score 1):

Your test is failing because it's throwing an exception. You need to catch that exception, there are many ways to do it, and using [rejects](https://jestjs.io/docs/tutorial-async#rejects) helper is one of them:

```
it("should fail", async () => {
    (window.fetch as jest.Mock).mockResolvedValueOnce({
      ok: false,
    });
    await expect(fetchCars(1)).rejects.toEqual(/* error you are expecting*/);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a couple of ways to deal with this correctly. I think the issue is that you are awaiting your promise.

If you plan to use await then you must await the expect:

```
const result = fetchCars(1);
await expect(result).toEqual(Promise.reject());
// ✅ Correct setup
```

or you can just return the un-awaited promise:

```
const result = fetchCars(1);
return expect(result).toEqual(Promise.reject());
// ✅ Correct setup
```

If you don't return or await the expect, then you might notice you get a false positive:

```
const result = fetchCars(1);
expect(result).toEqual(Promise.reject());
// ❌ False positive!
```

I've created a [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/testing-rejects-epfuf?file=/src/App.test.js) showing you how to mock the fetch function and how to correctly set up the test including the incorrect ways. Have a play around with the Tests tab at the top right.